# Кодировка Maven, Windows

Tags: java, maven

Как правильно настроить кодировку Maven проекта для работы с кириллицей? Какую кодировку использовать, CP866 или Windows-1251? Нужен пример POM файла с полностью настроенной кодировкой и пояснением какая кодировка должна быть в консоли и системе Windows, или ссылки на ресурсы. В консоли я знаю используется CP866, в системе Windows 1251, если я не ошибаюсь. Знаю кодировка проекта задаётся `<project.build.sourceEncoding>windows-1251</project.build.sourceEncoding>`, но ещё я видел что задают кодировку в maven-compiler-plugin, maven-resources-plugin и используют `<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>`, кто может объяснить в чём тут дело?

Мой проект в кодировке Windows 1251, но приведённая в примере функция требует явного указания кодировки CP866 для корректного извлечения, почему? Пробовал менять кодировку на CP866 при запуске jar файла в консоли, не помогает, весь проект корректно отображается, выполняет функции, почему то только при извлечении архива проблемы с кодировкой файлов на кириллице. При указании Windows-1251 в классе файлы извлекаются некорректно. Только CP866.

Использую net.lingala.zip4j.

```
public void Izvlecheniye(String AdresArkhiva, String AdresProgramm){

        try {

            ZipFile ZIPFayl = new ZipFile(AdresArkhiva);

            //ZIPFayl.setFileNameCharset("IBM866");

            ZIPFayl.extractAll(AdresProgramm);

            File Fayl = new File(AdresArkhiva);

            Fayl.delete();

            out.println("\n\n            Извлечено");
        }

        catch(ZipException Isklyucheniye) {

            out.println("\n\n            Ошибка");

            out.println("\n                " + Isklyucheniye.getMessage());

        }

    }
```

Comment: Не понял, причем здесь maven?

Comment: @Barmaley А что не так? Задаётся же кодировка в POM файле и настройках проекта Maven. Ещё влияет кодировка консоли и кодировка указанная при считывании или выводе текста. Кодировку при вводе-выводе я не задавал. Используется кодировка указанная в POM файле и в системе.

Comment: а почему не писать все в UTF-8?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Потому что Windows XP не поддерживает UTF-8.

Comment: @ELe о какой поддержке вы говорите?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chcp.mspx

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Вы можете мне сказать за что отвечает эта строчка в POM?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> А именно UTF-8. Надо ли менять на Windows 1251? Эта кодировка самого POM которую не нужно менять?

Comment: @ELe вы понимает в чем смысл статьи ссылку на которую вы дали?

Comment: @Mikhailvaysman Поддерживаемые кодировки консоли Windows XP?

Comment: @ELe нет. Там описано как пользоваться утилитой по смене кодовых страниц. И написаны вариант (не все) кодовых страниц. Воспользуйтесь ответом который вам дали. Если вы будете использовать UTF8 в вашей программе, то проблем не будет. Но при выводе на консоль не забывайте указывать кодировку 866 и Java все перекодирует для вас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понял точно проблематику, поэтому пройдусь по нескольким моментам. Что-нибудь да поможет.

Если в проекте нет жестких требований к кодировке, то лучше везде работать с кодировкой `utf-8`. То есть ваша IDE - среда разработки (IDEA, Eclipse, NetBeans IDE и т.п.) создает файл `pom.xml` и другие java-файлы по умолчанию в кодировке `utf-8`. Проверьте, что все java-файлы проекта и файл проекта `pom.xml` находятся в `utf-8` кодировке.
В частности, в первой строке файла `pom.xml` должно быть: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

**Далее, начните с простого** - в первой версии приложения работайте только с english-текстом, везде передавайте только его, во всех используемых файлах должна быть только кодировка `utf-8`. Сделайте так, чтобы всё заработало на english-тексте. Даже из java-исходников уберите тексты и комменты на русском. Я уверен, что всё заработает!

И когда все заработает - аккуратно добавляйте кириллицу (или что там нужно) и смотрите с какими ошибками падает сборка или работа приложения. Пишите об конкретных ошибках - будем разбираться на более частных случаях.

Comment: Я поэтому и выбрал Windows-1251 потому что на UTF-8 были проблемы с кодировкой. Не помню какие. Я попробую использовать сейчас UTF-8.

Comment: Попробуйте и прямо в своем вопросе дополните: нажмите "править" и укажите что именно делали и какая ошибка вылезла.